# Accidentally deleted /etc/apache2/ folder, what can I do?

Tags: apache, apache2, homebrew

I tried things like "brew install homebrew/apache/httpd24" but nothing seems to retrieve the "/etc/apache2" folder. What can I do?

Comment: Sounds like you are on a Mac. Do you have Time Machine backups? Depending on how you deleted the folder, it may also still be in Trash.

Comment: Yes I'm on a mac. I don't have a backup and it's not in the trash. Is there a way to re-install it?

Comment: Homebrew doesn’t write outside of `/usr/local` so it won’t help you get your `/etc/apache2` folder back.

Comment: @aleonstackoverflow Did you find a way to reinstall it? I just accidentally deleted /etc/apache2 as well.

Answer (score 10):

if you're on Ubuntu 14.04, this worked for me , you can check :

```
    sudo apt-get remove --purge apache2 apache2-utils
    sudo apt-get install --reinstall  apache2 apache2-utils
```